# Update React Version on SharePoint Server 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, react

From what I've been able to tell, SharePoint Server 2019 is locked to React@15.6.2. Is there a way to update this to a more modern version? Is this something that a CU would update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and do not expect any updates to React or other SPFx components in SharePoint 2019 (outside of potential security issues).

Comment: There have been a ton of improvements and changes to the React library since September 25, 2017, it's a shame.